# How to install libdbusmenu-qt on Ubuntu 16.04 to compile BitBudget 1.1

Tags: software-installation

I need to install this library so I can install another program to monitor data usage, but I can't install the library because nowhere I find the download tells me how to install it.

I already downloaded c make but its just so complicated and I need help.

I've tried in terminal Make C make and install ./configure and a really long command that I found on one site but nothing worked.

I need the dev version of the library

EDIT: I'm installing bitbudget-1.1

Comment: which program you were trying to install?

Comment: i am installing bit budget

Comment: `libdbusmenu-qt5` should be available in the default repository of Ubuntu 16.04.  `apt-cache policy libdbusmenu-qt5` lists version `0.9.3+16.04.20160218-0ubuntu1`. Regarding the dev version - it should be `libdbusmenu-qt5-dev` then i guess - as well available via the default repositories.

Comment: @dufte so its preinstalled is that what you mean?

Comment: No, but it is available to be installed using `apt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you are looking for can be installed like this:

```
sudo apt install libdbusmenu-qt-dev
```

or specifically `qt5` version `sudo apt install libdbusmenu-qt5-dev` (either one works)

**However**, You may not be able to use the `BitBudget` binary once you have built it. I can build it successfully, but it won't run on my system, as it hasn't been updated for so long.

Assuming you downloaded the bitbudget tarball from Launchpad [here](https://launchpad.net/bitbudget) to the `Downloads` directory, do:

```
sudo apt install g++ libdbusmenu-qt-dev
cd Downloads
tar xf bitbud*
cd bitbud*
qmake BitBudget.pro
make
qmake bitbudget-daemon.pro
make
```

Check that the binary works: `./BitBudget` (for me it segfaults). If it fails for you too, then you can just delete the whole directory.

If it works, then install to the `/opt` directory

```
sudo mkdir /opt/BitBudget
sudo cp BitBudget /opt/BitBudget
sudo cp bitbudget-daemon /opt/BitBudget/
sudo cp bitbudget.desktop /usr/share/applications/
sudo cp data/bitbudget.svg /usr/share/pixmaps/
```

This includes installing a desktop launcher to run the program so you should be able to run it just by clicking the icon, if it works on your system.

Comment: this helped alot thankyou it worked

Comment: that's awesome! I'm really glad it worked for you :) @UbuntuN00B